# Work with relative URLs when using UIWebView's -loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How to give the `baseURL:` when using UIWebView's `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`?

When `baseURL` is set to `nil`, relative URLs (html pages within the tree) are not working at all.

Comment: When we use [webview loadRequest] method, the base URL is set to nil in the request it self, and the relative URLs are working well. But when we use [webview loadData: MIMEType: textEncodingName: baseURL:] we have to set the base url, otherwise relative URLs are not working. how to set the base URLs by the properties of the "request" or "response"? This is a situation where we have to use both internal links and external sites (ex. google) in the same webview.

Comment: Also, when we use loadData method, functions such as  history.back() are not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

it path to resources:

```
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:type textEncodingName:name baseURL:[NSURL urlWithString:pathToResources]];
```